# How to get current_app for using with reverse in multi-deployable reusable Django application?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm writing reusable app. And I want to deploy it several times.

Here is urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^carphotos/', include('webui.photos.urls', app_name='car-photos') ),
(r'^userphotos/', include('webui.photos.urls',  app_name='profile-photos') ),)
```

and photos/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('webui.photos.views',
url(r'^$', album_list, name="album-list" )
url(r'^newalbum/$', album_page, {'create': True}, name="album-create"),)
```

On the album_list view I want to show url for creating new album album_page.

I found that I have to use parameter current_app of reverse function to get proper URL.

But how to get this current_app?
I thought the answer is something simple. But I can't find it in django documentation.

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After exploring this topic for several days, I found that it isn't natural to mount django app more than once.

There is implementation of pluggable applications pattern:
http://github.com/nowells/django-pluggables.
It looks too tricky for me.

So I decided to move repeated functionality to custom tags and duplicate templates for each usage of my app. I hope using custom tags and extend feature help me to follow DRY principle.

Comment: *it isn't natural to mount django app more than once* - [Not TRUE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse).

Answer (score 12):

I know this is a pretty old question... but I think I found a solution:

As Will Hardy suggested you'll have to keep `app_name` the same for both instances (or not define it at all, it will default to the app the included urls reside in). Define a separate namespace for each app instance though:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^carphotos/', include('webui.photos.urls', app_name="webui_photos", namespace='car-photos') ),
    (r'^userphotos/', include('webui.photos.urls', app_name="webui_photos", namespace='profile-photos') ),
)
```

Now comes the slightly tricky part of setting the currently active app instance (namespace) in your views. Meaning you have to find out which app instance is active and pass it to `RequestContext`.

To find the currently active app, `django.urls.resolve` can be used:

```
r = resolve(request.path)
r.app_name  # the app name
r.namespace # the the currently active instance
```

So you'll have to update your views (this assumes using the class based views) accordingly:

```
from django.urls import resolve
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class AlbumCreateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'path/to/my/template.html'
    
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        response_kwargs['current_app'] = resolve(self.request.path).namespace
        return super(AlbumPageView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
```

Now the url tag will automatically reverse to the correct namespace and still allow reversing to a specific app namespace if needed:

```
{% url webui_photos:album-create %} {# returns the url for whatever app is current #}
{% url car-photos:album-create %}
{% url profile-photos:album-create %}
```

To reverse urls in views, the current app instance has to be passed in manually:

```
reverse('webui_photos:album-create', current_app=resolve(self.request.path).namespace))
```

Comment: Since v1.10 resolve() is in `django.urls`, not accessible via `django.core.urlresolvers` since v2.

Answer (score 1):

In your urls, you have a different `app_name` even though it's the same app. Set the `app_name` to the same thing, and set `namespace` uniquely for each instance. eg.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^carphotos/', include('webui.photos.urls', app_name="webui_photos", namespace='car-photos') ),
(r'^userphotos/', include('webui.photos.urls', app_name="webui_photos", namespace='profile-photos') ),)
```

Then provide the `current_app` argument when using reverse. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse and http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

[edit] after re-reading your question:

you don't need to provide the `current_app` argument if you are using the `{% url %}` tag. As far as I'm lead to believe, it will automatically access a template variable called `current_app`, which is automatically set based on the matched url.

Comment: I tried this code, and it doesn't solve the problem. As I found, current_app is the argument of Context or RequestContext which I have to provide explicitly. And how to get it is the question of this page. BTW after setting namespace argument, my urls become broken as described at http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11559

Answer (score -4):

I believe that's what the [`sites`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) framework is for.

Comment: I read docs you suggested. I don't think it's right answer. According to documentation Sites framework is useful when you want to share information between sites, but in my case there is one site only. Technically it is possible to deploy my photos app on different sub-domains, but I think its wrong to create separate domains for every instance of reusable app.