# Reversing namespaced URLs in Django: multiple instances of the same app

Tags: django, namespaces

I've been working with Django for a while now (currently on version 1.2), but just recently started working on an app that needs to support multiple instances.  E.g., the project `urls.py` file will include it twice, under two different namespaces, like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^instance1/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='instance1')),
    (r'^instance2/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='instance2')),
)
```

I was going along fine, until I realized I needed to figure out what to do about all the internal calls to `reverse()` (or the template calls to the `{% url %}` filter).  For instance, let's say I'm doing something like the following in one of my views:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_name'))
```

or something like this in one of my templates:

```
<a href="{% url view_name %}">link text</a>
```

...where `view_name` is the name of a URL pattern contained in `myapp.urls`.  Since I'm using namespaces, this will raise an error: there is no view called `view_name`. Rather, I have to tell it either `instance1:view_name` or `instance2:view_name`.  But doing this dynamically is stumping me.

I did some looking and it looks like the `current_app` argument, passed to either `Context` or `RequestContext`, was designed to help with this, but it's not clear at all how to dynamically pass the *right* application name to `current_app`.  So what's the right way to tell Django which namespace to use?

EDIT: My use case is to use a single installation of the app multiple times. That is, it only exists on disk once, but gets included multiple times in the project's root `urls.py` (each time under a different namespace, as in my example above).  With this in mind, is there any good way to keep track of which namespace a view/template is being called from, and make any use of `reverse()` or `{% url %}` stick within the same namespace?  I know Django 1.3 will provide some extra features that could help with this (namely, the [new and improved `resolve()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#resolve)), but surely there's a good way to do this now...

Comment: My answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030225/how-to-get-current-app-for-using-with-reverse-in-multi-deployable-reusable-djang/13249060#13249060 applies here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a very nice solution, but since you use the same text for your namespace and initial part of the URL path, you can extract that element from `request.path` (`request.path.split('/')[1]`) and set that as `current_app` in the request context, or just use it as the namespace in views.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces point 2.

You could do that e.g. in a context processor (if you want to use the namespace in a template).

For views you could write a decorator that feeds your function an extra kwarg "namespace" and use it as:

```
@feed_namespace
def view1(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ns = kwargs['namespace']
```

or just write a reverse_namespaced function with an extra param (the request) where the function gets the namespace from, and use it instead of reverse.

Of course if you do this you will always have to use a request path/namespace for this app

Comment: Thanks, the first idea (using part of the path to get the namespace) is what I ended up doing.  If I need to do this again before 1.3 comes out, your other ideas could be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

A lot has changed since the question was posted but for future googlers (like myself) it might be useful to point out that `request` has the namespace now (at least since 1.7 as shown in [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#id4).

From what I understood we should be able to simply pass `current_app` positional argument to `reverse`/`redirect` but I couldn't get it to work so I ended up creating an help method for this purpose:

```
def __redirect(request, viewname, *args, **kwargs):
    to = viewname

    if callable(to):
        to = viewname.__module__ + '.' + viewname.__name__
    if request.resolver_match.namespace:
        to = '%s:%s' % (request.resolver_match.namespace, to)

    return redirect(
        to,
        *args,
        **kwargs
    )
```

I'm using `redirect` here but all the arguments are passed on to `reverse`, so it's the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is a doc page about reversing namespaced urls.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces

Either `reverse('instance1:myapp.urls.some_view')` or `reverse('instance1:view_name')` should work, or both :) - i've never tried this myself.

Comment: Those would work, true--but that would then be hard-coding the app to work only with specific values for the namespace.  I want the app to not care what namespace it's assigned in the user's main urls.py file: it should automatically use the 'right' one, adjusting depending on which namespace the view was called from (or which the template is being rendered in).

Answer (score 2):

The `current_app` variable is something you have to set yourself to something you like.

Personally I'd recommend setting it to something like `__name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0]` so you get `spam` in `spam/views.py`.

But you can define it to be anything you like, as long as your app name is consistent with what you define in your urls file.

Comment: Hm, perhaps my mention of current_app is a red herring.  Assuming I'm using the same app (same views.py file, and so on), but importing the same app/urls.py file twice (two different includes in the project's urls.py file, under two namespaces, like in my example above), is there a way to automatically get my `reverse()` and `{% url %}` calls to stick with the same namespace they're being called from?

Comment: @peppergrower: not as far as I know. I have opted to add the namespace to the `reverse` and `{% url %}` delcarations myself. Saves a little trouble. It would be trivial to wrap `render_to_response` and `reverse` with a version that includes you `current_app` though. Something like this might suffice: `reverse = lambda *a, **kw: original_reverse(current_app=YOUR_CURRENT_APP, *a, **kw)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're not too tied to namespaces, you could instead write your urls.py to be like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^(P<instance>/)', 'controllers.route_me'),
)
```

This will make a call to the controllers.route_me function and pass it the request, plus the string 'instance', which you could handle this way:

```
# (in controllers.py)
def route_me(request, instance):
    # you now have complete control, and do what you need to do with the 'instance' and 'request' vars
    pass
```