# How to make reverse URL to current instance of application?

Tags: django, django-urls

**Django version: 1.8 or 1.9**

Reusing a `myapp` several times based on different URLs in `mysite/urls.py` with:

```
url(r'^myapp_1/', include('myapp.urls')),
url(r'^myapp_2/', include('myapp.urls')),
```

The `myapp/urls.py` is:

```
url('^rev/$', views.rev, name='rev'),
```

So I need to make a URL reverse, like a `reverse('rev')`, that creates a reverse URL in the same `myapp` instance, which for different URLs looks trivial as:

- .../myapp_1/rev/ => .../myapp_1/rev/
- .../myapp_2/rev/ => .../myapp_2/rev/

I found a number of related questions without a nice solution, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230687/reversing-namespaced-urls-in-django-multiple-instances-of-the-same-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477090/django-redirect-using-reverse-to-a-url-that-relies-on-query-strings), but they appear to be for much older Django versions than 1.8/1.9, and it appears that the reverse URL scheme has changed.  However, I have not been able to decipher the [Django documentation on Reversing namespaced URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) to give this functionality, which I thought was trivial, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include `myapp.urls` twice, using the same application namespace, but a different instance namespace:

```
url(r'^myapp_1/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp1', app_name='myapp')),
url(r'^myapp_2/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp2', app_name='myapp')),
```

Then, in your code, reverse the url using the application namespace, and pass the current instance namespace in the `current_app` parameter:

```
reverse('myapp:rev', current_app=request.resolver_match.namespace)
```

When using the `{% url %}` tag in a template, you cannot pass the current namespace directly, but you can set the `current_app` attribute on the request for the same effect:

```
# in your view
request.current_app = request.resolver_match.namespace

# in your template
{% url 'myapp:rev' %}
```

In 1.9, this has slightly changed. You specify the `app_name` in the included url configuration, and the `namespace` in the call to `include()`, like this:

`mysite/urls.py`:

```
url(r'^myapp_1/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp1')),
url(r'^myapp_2/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp2')),
```

`myapp/urls.py`:

```
app_name = 'myapp'
urlpatterns = [
    url('^rev/$', views.rev, name='rev'),
]
```

Another change in 1.9 is that the `{% url %}` template tag now uses the namespace of the current request by default. If you need to reverse an url in the same namespace, you no longer have to set `request.current_app` explicitly. You still need to pass the current app if you use `reverse()`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough description.  I have tried this on Django ver. 1.8.4, and with works nicely for both `reverse` and `{% url %}`.  Looks like the ver. 1.9 update is reasonable, so the app itself can define the app. namespace that it will use internally in the in reverse or url calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use [namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) in you urls.py.

Edit: The answers you linked do not look that wrong. What is the specific problem with these? I linked the docs for version 1.8, if there are differences.

Comment: How will a namespace like with `url(r'^myapp_1/', include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp_1'))` make it possible to generate different reverse URLs based on same code in the view ?