# Does Django `extends` accept namespace resolved templates?

Tags: python, django

Well I tried:

*proj/templates/registration/register.html*:

```
{% extends "a:base.html" %}
```

*proj/proj/urls.py:*

```
from a import urls as a_urls
import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^accounts/register$', views.register),
                       url(r'^a/', include(a_urls, namespace='a')),
                   )
```

`register`:

```
def register(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html')
```

Didn't work (*TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/register*).

`{% extends {% url "a:base.html" %} %}` didn't work either (*'extends' takes one argument*).

What I was trying do was extend a template of an app (apparent from the directory paths) without having to type the path. `base.html` could be there in multiple apps in the root of their respective `templates` dir so I want to refer to one of them by namespace.

So is there a way to use templates through namespace resolution in `extends`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking to do. What do you want to use for the value of ```{% extends %}```?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030225/how-to-get-current-app-for-using-with-reverse-in-multi-deployable-reusable-djang/13249060#13249060

Comment: @mattm not really. My use case is specific inside `extends`.

Comment: @schillingt elaborated in the question

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a namespace in a template path, so it's not clear what you're trying to do. And using URLs makes no sense either: the path has nothing to do with a URL, it's simply a file path relative to your TEMPLATE_DIRS base.

Comment: True url doesn't make sense. What I was trying do was extend a template of an app (apparent from the directory paths) without having to type the path. `base.html` could be there in multiple apps in the root of their respective `templates` dir so I want to refer to one of them by namespace.