# Overriding django current app in a django template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to override the current_app withing a template in Django 1.11:

search_form.html filled by views.search:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <p> {% url 'book:index' %} </p>
        <p> {% url 'book2:index' %} </p>
        {% with current_app as "book2" %}
            <p> {% url 'book:index' %} </p>
        {% endwith %}
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^search/', include("books.urls", namespace='book', app_name='book')),
    url(r'^search2/', include("books.urls", namespace='book2', app_name='book')),
    ...
]
```

books' urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.search, name="index")
]
```

The output is:

```
/search/

/search2/

/search/
```

I should be getting the following:

```
/search/

/search2/

/search2/
```

This solution is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7365593/7829566):

I think something could have changed in Django so this solution doesn't work anymore.

`reverse(..., current_app = "books2")` in views still works and shows: "/search2/" though.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13249060/3042057 - check the last code with using current_app. Does that solves your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that the last code in that post uses reverse() function in views (which works as I stated in my post); however, the problem is that I want to override current_app within the template (not within the views).